# Why are my Nuxt/vue pages getting blocked by robot.txt?

Tags: vue.js, seo, nuxt.js, robots.txt, google-search-console

*This is not a question about best practice within SEO but a question about how to setup config.js and script sections correctly in VUE*

I have build my site with Vue/Nuxt and what have earlier been a walk in the park for me with angular, are now causing errors.

My overall problem is that I am not sure if I have build my script section right as my pages are not getting indexed by Google. In my nuxt.config.js file I have build my sitemap, robot.txt and some general meta-tags. For every page I have build dynamic meta tags in their script section.

**Google Search Console is giving 3 type of errors.**

1. Some pages are blocked by my robot.txt
2. Some pages is said to be dublicated rel-canonical
3. When inspecting my site it cant fint pages without typing in '/' at the end of the URL. This is also seen when using Screaming Frog SEO tool.

My assumption is that I am missing some form of a redirect that makes the crawler index pages ending with '/' as those are getting indexed fine in Search Console?

**Nuxt.config.js file** (Sections, not all content is showed)

```
    head: {
    title: 'NorthArc',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { name: 'language', content: 'da_DK' },
      { name: 'robots', content: 'index, follow' },
      { name: 'og:type', content: 'website' },
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
    ]
  },

sitemap: {
    path: '/sitemap.xml',
    hostname: 'https://northarc.dk/',
    routes: [
      {
        url: '/',
        changefreq: 'monthly',
        priority: 1,
      },
      {
        url: '/team/',
        changefreq: 'monthly',
        priority: 1,
      },
      {
        url: '/groen-planlaegning/',
        changefreq: 'monthly',
        priority: 1,
      },
      {
        url: '/strategisk-samarbejde/',
        changefreq: 'monthly',
        priority: 1,
      },
      {
        url: '/blog/',
        changefreq: 'monthly',
        priority: 1,
      },
      {
        url: '/blog/er-ruteplanlaegning-svaert/',
        changefreq: 'monthly',
        priority: 1,
      },
      {
        url: '/blog/automatisk-ruteplanlaegning/',
        changefreq: 'monthly',
        priority: 1,
      },
      {
        url: '/faq/',
        changefreq: 'monthly',
        priority: 1,
      },
      {
        url: '/contact/',
        changefreq: 'monthly',
        priority: 1,
      },
      {
        url: '/policies/',
        changefreq: 'monthly',
        priority: 1,
      }
    ]
  },

  robots: {
    UserAgent: 'Googlebot',
    Disallow: ['/roi', '/pricing'],
    Sitemap: 'https://northarc.dk/sitemap.xml',

  },
```

**Script section from a page that is said to be blocked bt robot.txt and has dublicated rel-canonical.**

```
    <script>
export default {
  name: 'home',
  head() {
    return {
      title: 'test',
      meta: [
        { 
        hid: 'description', 
        name: 'description', 
        content: 'test', 
        },
        { hid: 'robots', name: 'robots', content: 'index, follow' },
      {hid: 'og-title', property: 'og:title', content: 'Fjern spildtid på vejen og minimere antal kørte kilometer'},
      {hid: 'og-url', property: 'og:url', content: 'https://northarc.dk/groen-planlaegning'},
      {hid: 'og-description', property: 'og:description', content: 'test'},
      {hid: 'og-image', property: 'og:image', content: '/Applications/Northarc_landing/assets/Preview_sløret.jpg'},
      ],
      link: [
      { 
      rel: 'canonical', 
      href: 'https://northarc.dk/groen-planlaegning/' 
      }
    ] 
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**Notes:** (change-log)

1. I have tried to add a '/' to all sites URL in my sitemap and at the rel-canonical for the pages example showed above.
2. I have tried to change the user of robot.txt to googlebot to disallow two pages. Before the user was set to '*' where it still blocked some pages.

Answer (score 0):

By default Nuxt allows each route without or with a trailing slash, example:

- https://northarc.dk/blog
- https://northarc.dk/blog/

It can be detect as duplicate content by crawlers.
So you can define which is the main URL with the "canonical" header.

But if you want keep URLs only with a trailing slash at end, you have to allow only route with a trailing slash by the router configuration:

```js
// nuxt.config.js

router: {
  trailingSlash: true
}
```

See docs https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-router#trailingslash

---

in addition,
you don't need to hardcoded all your routes in the sitemap-module config, it's automatic for all static routes, eg.:

```js
// nuxt.config.js

sitemap: {
  hostname: 'https://northarc.dk',
  defaults: {
    changefreq: 'monthly',
    priority: 1,
    trailingSlash: true
  },
  exclude: ['roi', 'pricing'],
  trailingSlash: true // if necessary
},
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas 

Thanks you for your answer. I have tried to implement them and are looking forward to see its results.

The new sitemap has correctly discovered 10 URLs now but are still saying that my robot.txt are blocking 6 of them, even tough that they all have the same script section. 

Both lines below are added to every sites script sectiob:
{ hid: 'robots', name: 'robots', content: 'index, follow' },
link: [ { rel: 'canonical', href: 'https://northarc.dk/groen-planlaegning/' } ]

Comment: @ChristofferHøeg can you give us this list of 6 blocked routes?

Comment: /blog, /policies, /strategisk-samarbejde, /blog/er-ruteplanlaegning-svaert, /blog/automatisk-ruteplanlaegning, /groen-planlaegning